# technology agnostic frontend pattern and/or templates for payment forms on websites

Tags: design-patterns, web-applications, payment-processing

Does anyone know of good frontend templates for implementing payment gateways in web apps?

When implementing a payment form there's always a bunch of **app flow stuff** you have to do to try and avoid mainly two scenarios:

1. Stop the user from submitting payments twice (maybe using the back button, or refresh or whatever).
2. Dealing with payment transactions that may take a long time and/or fail.

What I'm looking for are generic tried and tested front-end patterns, or ideally, templates which handle this.

It would be great if I could download some html templates with javascript that were tried and tested, where the server side bit is just being emulated.

Or if there was a solid pattern that described this. For example,

- what do you put in the session,
- how do you trigger the ajax request on the "next" page for dealing with a long running process,
- how do you avoid the back button problem,
- how do you resume transactions that the user stopped by mistake...

that kind of thing.

Anyone know of such a thing?

The lots of ways to achieve this, I'm thinking, is there a solid way, without me having to reinvent the wheel!